# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/gd2'

Tags: sockets, mysqli, pdo, mbstring, gd2

I recently bought a new Macbook pro with php 7.1 installed and everything was working fine since I tried to upgrade php to 7.2 using **homebrew**. When I try to show my version of php with `php -v`, and it works but  it returns me the following warnings :

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/gd2' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/gd2, 0x0009):
>   closured error in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mbstring' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mbstring,
>   0x0009): closured error in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mysqli' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mysqli,
>   0x0009): closured error in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/pdo_mysql' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/pdo_mysql,
>   0x0009): closured error in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/sockets' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/sockets,
>   0x0009): closured error in Unknown on line 0

It seems to be an error with gd2, mbstring, mysqli, pdo_mysql and sockets files but they do not exist on the no-debug-non-zts-20160303/ folder... 
Is there a way using **homebrew** to reinstall all these missing files ?

Thanks